How can I Test 'react-slick' library with Jest?
I have been trying to achieve 100% coverage in my Slider component, but I need to test the branches of these functions:
const nextSlide = () => {
    if (sliderRef.current) sliderRef.current?.slickNext();
};
const prevSlide = () => {
  if (sliderRef.current) sliderRef.current?.slickPrev();
};

I've searched for documentation on how to mock the library and spy both slickNext() and slickPrev() methods are called, but haven't found answers.
I already tried with this mocks from AI:
jest.mock('react-slick', () => {
      const React = require('react');`your text`
      return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        slickNext: jest.fn() // Mocking slickNext method
      }));
});
expect(Slider().slickNext).toHaveBeenCalled();

_
const slickNextMock = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(Slider.prototype, 'slickNext').mockImplementation(slickNextMock);

_
jest.mock('react-slick', () => {
      return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          slickNext: jest.fn(),
          slickPrev: jest.fn()
        };
      });
    });

None of them has worked.
